# require module from different - separately generated - webpack bundle

Tags: module, webpack, bundle

I'm building an app that can load various modules (other bundles generated by different webpack configs) on demand. The `BaseModule` is responsible for knowing when to load which bundle and exports some default classes like `BaseUtils`. The module itself is not aware of all the possible modules/bundles it may need to load.

`TestModule` is one of those modules that is loaded on demand at runtime by the `BaseModule`, and `TestModule` wants to use `BaseUtils`.

The question is: Is it possible to `require('basemodule/BaseUtils')` in `TestModule`, which has its own webpack.config.js file, with `BaseModule` listed as external? That is, is there a way to let the generated testmodule bundle reuse the modules available in the generated basemodule bundle? Or does BaseModule neccesarily need to be exported to global variable?

Comment: This interests me as well. I am having a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406279/apply-commonschunkplugin-on-different-config-exports-in-webpack)

Comment: Can you please share your App structure which includes BaseModule as well as TestModule?

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Just a suggestion. I did not try this.

One way i think of is to bundle all other modules (`TestModule`) first and bundle your app which has `BaseModule` next. By this, `TestModule` bundle would be available in place when `BaseModule` is bundled. And `TestModule` bundle file should be available in the `BaseModule`'s folder as webpack needs this when `BaseModule` is bundled. So your `TestModule`'s webpack.config would have output path pointing to some folder under `BaseModule`'s src folder.

Note: `BaseUtils` should be a `CommonChunk` because it is required by `TestModule` as well as `BaseModule`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not an option for me since many modules will be created over time by different people after the basemodule is completed.